# Concatenate between two Razor elements and save value in Database table column in the POST ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a static dropdownlist and editor need to take the selected value from the dropdownlist and the written value from the editor and make a concatenation between the two values and save it in a Database table column in the post ActionResult:

**This is the View:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Term.Description", new List<SelectListItem>
{
new SelectListItem{ Text="Winter", Value = "Winter-" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="Spring", Value = "Spring-" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="Fall", Value = "Fall-" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="Summer", Value = "Summer-" }
}, new { @class = "description-text" })
@Html.Editor("TermYear","", new {  htmlAttributes = new { @class = "description-text", placeholder = "2018", data_placeholder = "  " } })
```

**ActionResult**:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Term term, int[] applicantTypes)
{
    ModelState.Remove("ApplicantTypes");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (applicantTypes != null && applicantTypes.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in applicantTypes)
            {
                term.ApplicantTypes.Add(db.ApplicantTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApplicantTypeID == item));
            }
        }
        db.Terms.Add(term);
        db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.ApplicantTypes = new MultiSelectList(db.ApplicantTypes, "ApplicantTypeID", "Name", term.ApplicantTypes.Select(x => x.ApplicantTypeID));
    return View(term);
}
```

Finally, I need the `Term.Description = DropDownListSelectedValue-EditorValue'

Comment: Your generating the dropdownlist with a `name` attribute that has no relationship to your model (unless `Term` also contains a property name `Term` which is a complex object containing a property named `Description`. What are the properties of your model

Comment: I have a table 'Term' with a Column Description

Comment: Its working if you select a value from the dropdownlist and it will be saved in the database but need before saving it in the DB make the concatenation with the Editor

Comment: Then it should be `@Html.DropDownList("Description", ...)` or better `@Html.DropDownList(m => m.Descripton, ....)`. So are you wanting so update value of `Description` to (say) `Winter-2016` assuming the value of  `TermYear` is 2016?

Comment: Yes that's right, but take care about the dropdownlist if `m=>m.Description` will return the value of Winter-2016 but i need the selected list as you shown above.

Comment: So just do `term.Description = term.Description + term.TermYear;` before you call `db.Terms.Add(term);` But you really should be using a view model for this, and then mapping its properties to a new instance of the data model

Comment: but the `TermYear` not a column in the Term Table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127703/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ahmed-hossam-alhansy).